# Swipe for specific duration with Appium Java client 6.0.0

Tags: appium

The Appium Java client version 6.0.0 removed the `driver.swipe(fromX, toX, fromY, toY, duration)` API. From what I can tell, we are now supposed to use the TouchAction class to achieve the same, using the following code:

```
(new TouchAction(driver))
    .press(PointOption.point(fromX, fromY))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
    .moveTo(PointOption.point(offsetX, offsetY))
    .release()
    .perform();
```

I think we have a gap there, because the duration of the swipe sounds like something that should be passed along in the `moveTo()` call and there is no method overload to achieve that.

The code I pasted above performs the actions: press, wait, move, release. What I would like to do is: press, then **immediately** start moving and make sure the swipe gesture spans exactly 1 second, then release. What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to chain the waitAction() to happen after the moveTo() rather than after the press(). This will control the moveTo() gesture to take as long as you're defining in the waitAction():

```
(new TouchAction(driver))
    .press(PointOption.point(fromX, fromY))
    .moveTo(PointOption.point(offsetX, offsetY))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
    .release()
    .perform();
```

Comment: I just tested your suggestion on Android and it doesn't behave as expected, unfortunately. It performs a flick gesture and then I'm instantly taken all the way to the end of the page. Kind of makes sense, since we're doing a `press` and then instantly move to the end point of the swipe, which is the definition of a flick gesture. So, for the time being, I'm back to square one.

Comment: Add more duration + try adding another waitAction after release? The more duration you use, the more relaxed the gesture will be.